# "Error inflating class fragment" with google map

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I tried to make a sample project using Google Map, but I couldn't. 
Help me please!

Test Device : Android 4.0.4

Error Message :

```
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.test_googlemap/com.example.test_googlemap.MainActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
inflating class fragment 12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-29 23:45:32.605:
E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-29 23:45:32.605:
E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-29 23:45:32.605:
E/AndroidRuntime(9437): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:271)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
com.example.test_googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     ... 11 more 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437): Caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment 12-29 23:45:32.605:
E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369) 12-29
23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):   at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
12-29 23:45:32.605: E/AndroidRuntime(9437):     ... 20 more
```

Source Code :

```
package com.example.test_googlemap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test_googlemap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="I removed it!"/>
        </application>    
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.Test_GoogleMap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.Test_GoogleMap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are extending `FragmentActivity`, indicating that you are trying to use the Android Support package backport of fragments. However, your `<fragment>` element refers to `MapFragment`, which is for the native API Level 11 edition of fragments.

Replace `MapFragment` with `SupportMapFragment`, and that should clear up this specific crash.

Comment: @user1875940: Then you have a problem with your API key or something. Check LogCat for messages.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Log cat show some messages that 'server return 3...'.

Comment: Yes this was exactly my problem. I copied and pasted directly from the API and it uses MapFragment. For anyone having this problem, this is a nice quick start guide to Maps API V2 https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

Comment: Thanks @RyanR I have been breaking my head over this issue for the past several hours. Finally your guide, fixed it for me.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @VisheshJoshi It's not my guide, but I'm glad it helped you as it helped me :D

Comment: I have followed same but i am not able to resolve it. So please provide detail step so i can resolve it.

Comment: This doesn't work into Fragment instead of Activity. Have a crash with both `MapFragment ` or `SupportMapFragment` while trying create my fragment with entire map fragment at second time. At first map showing normally.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I did the mistake to only add one of the 2 following tags.
**Note that you are also missing one of these two**

> ```
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
>             android:value="<YOUR VALUE>"/>
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
>             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
> ```

The actual error is really misleading, as you might be thinking of some API level UI issue.

Answer (score 4):

Some times you are using both -

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="<YOUR VALUE>"
/>
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="<YOUR VALUE>"
/>
```

Make sure , Don't use both ... 
if you need Location , Places and maps then use geo.API_KEY
and if you need places and maps then use maps.v2.API_KEY

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer is correct but meaningful information i share with you, may be anyone facing same issue what i face

> If everything is woking same as google code then please check manifest file in my case i added geo key and map key that's why exception occurs,

**Note - do not add two keys in manifest file remove map key**

```
meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

above code and add this code.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/auto_location"/>

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem also  occurs when it is not able to inflate the Fragment class mentioned in the activity_main.xml(or the XML file present under res/layout), due to a SDK version incompatibility in the andriod_manifest.xml file.

The correct versions for SDK levels to get the map on an emulator is this:

```
     <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's an already answered question this error can also appear if you call the `super.onCreateView`in your fragment. It will crash at run time.

Be sure you overridden the `onCreateView` method and inflated your layout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to do two corrections to make this exception go away.

1. The activity should extend FragmentActivity and not Activity
2. Manifest file needs a uses-permission for ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE (my file already had INTERNET permission)

Answer (score 1):

This defect has been resolved in play services library v9.0.0. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021#makechanges

Answer (score 0):

Use the internet permission to be direct child of manifest file.. Like  below and try..

Also You should have the following for using map:

1.Should extend `Map activity` in your activity file

2.Should have API key  i didn't see any key in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: The OP is using Maps V2, where there is no `MapActivity`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Do u have valid Google Map API key?
2. try using

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends MapActivity{
    ... }
   ```

Comment: The OP is using Maps V2, where there is no `MapActivity`.