# Google Maps V2 - Error inflating class Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying my hand and Android Application Development. I'm currently using Eclipse (I can't remember the version, whatever the newest is). I've crossed a bridge where I just can't seem to grasp what I'm doing wrong. I'm attempting to use the Google Maps V2 API. I've been through several documents and tried several techniques, all of which lead to the same error:

```
Android.view.Inflate Exception: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
```

I've been pounding my face into the keys for 2 days straight trying to grasp what I'm doing wrong here.

Things I've done:

1. Started with a blank activity.
2. Project -> Properties -> Android -> *Project Build Target is Google APIs - 4.2 - API 17* - I've tried *every* other option as well (as long as above version 3.0, found it documented
3. Added the google-play-services_lib to my Package Explorer. I indicated that the google-play-services_lib was indeed `a library`.
4. Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add -> and I choose the location to the google-play-services_lib.
5. Included `android-support-v4.jar` as a dependency of my project.

I've tried so many different answers from questions similar to mine, but to no avail. :(
I can usually figure these things out, but maybe I'm just too overloaded.

My package explorer tree in eclipse looks like

1. google-play-services_lib
2. Svma

Here's the code:>

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testing.svma"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.testing.svma.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.testing.svma.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.testing.svma.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="SHA1_Generated_KEY_HERE" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.testing.svma;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

**Reference Documents**

1. I used [“Error inflating class fragment” with google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082851/error-inflating-class-fragment-with-google-map) to try and fix my issues.
2. I referenced [This google maps quick start guide](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) to create my project.
3. I had started initially with [the sample code from the Introduction to the Google Maps Android V2 Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro)
4. A whole slew of SO questions.

So, SO Community, what am I doing wrong? Why am I unable to grasp this simple concept.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing. My code works and it seems to be identical to yours. Maybe post the rest of the stack trace? Is there a second "Caused by:" ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have the same code/same problem! Try adding android:name="com.testing.svma.MainActivity" to "fragment" in the layout! It solved the issue for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:name="com.testing.svma.MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue, but I was using a MapFragment. I copy and pasted your XML and changed the "android:name" line to match my project. It worked! I also had to make a small code change. Had to include this ((SupportMapFragment)(this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap(); over my previous code. I have no idea why this worked, my code was working 2 days ago... I didn't even push a new update, I simply opened the application again and was getting all these errors discussed above.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the API level. I am stuck with implementing for API 8 and this didn't change anything for me. I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: This made my day. But why changing name fix the issue?

Answer (score 32):

I know this is probably a dead thread but just in case someone stumbles upon here having an identical problem - your manifest might be missing the following meta information:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Declare it within the `<application>` element and your code should work. I ran into the same issue following a youtube tutorial that skipped this step and only when carefully going through the original Google tutorial I noticed the missing code.

Anyway, hope this helps someone.

Comment: Importantly, make sure you add this meta tag within the application element!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, solved it by modifying the Manifest.
    This is my manifest.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="example.gps"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

        <permission 
               android:name="example.gps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
               android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
      <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
         <uses-sdk
           android:minSdkVersion="9"
           android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
         <uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
      <!-- External storage for caching. -->
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <!-- My Location -->
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
      <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
         <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>
      <!-- End of copy. -->

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="<YOUR VALUE>"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <activity
                android:name="example.gps.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

And the xml file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
```

The java class is

```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        {
           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           }
        }
```

That solved my problem

Comment: You should add **some description** to what changes you've made to make it work. While posted code may help someone, you should specify what the **code does**.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add google-play-services library reference to your project. If you are using Eclipse, you need to go to `Project->Properties->Android` and `Add` google-play-services library project.

ALTERNATIVELY,

You can modify `project.properties` file manually.
Try to add reference to your google_play_services library. So my `project.properties` file looks like:

```
# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../../../android-sdks/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

In your case path to google-play-services lib may be different

I tried to import your code and it crashed as well. When I modified properties file - I've got map running

Answer (score 3):

I spend a lot of time trying to solve this problem and after much reading and trying, I solved by changing the

`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`

for this

`public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

Had tried all the above answers over a period of a couple of days and then eventually this worked:

Project -> Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target

Changed the project build target to android 4.3(API 18) and clicked apply

In the manifest I then manually changed the min and target sdk versions:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

This now matches the `target=android-18` in the project.properties file (which resulted from the project build target change we did first)

I also tried `android:minSdkVersion="11"` which worked so the `targetSdkVersion`is the important bit.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Frequently the problem is in `Manifest.xml` , so be sure that you write the right permissions like :
`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zako.android.locationapi.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.zako.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.zako.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.zako.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="......" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`

don't forget `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
and `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I did the mistake to only add one of the 2 following tags.

The actual error is really misleading, as you might be thinking of some API level UI issue.

> ```
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
>             android:value="<YOUR VALUE>"/>
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
>             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
> ```

**Note that you are also missing one of these two**

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and I think it comes from this point: when I include the Google Play Service API I do not copy it in my workspace, I use the original one !!!

*Note*: You should be referencing a copy of the library that you copied to your source tree—you should not reference the library from the Android SDK directory.

Check this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have got similar problem that I resolved by right click `project->tools>add support library` ...
and `setup library`

I hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

Just include the following line of code on `onDestroy()`

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_location_sharing));

if(mapFragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fM = getFragmentManager();
    fM.beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commit();
```

It worked for me.Hopefully gonna work for you too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too and it was due to EXTERNAL PERMISSIONS. It has no sense but I added this permission and since then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Some of android 6.0 mobile this exception is bug
If unable to flat XML cause by

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Configuration android.content.res.Resources.getConfiguration()' on a null object reference
```

Then it is active bug in android
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827842

This can be solved by adding

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true" adding in activity tag
```

Answer (score 1):

using both meta data references was resolving the issue in my case:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="yourAPIkeyFromGoogleAPIConsole" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added API key to manifest and it helped

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem I just added the **API_KEY** to Manifest and every thing is fine.

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/map_api_key" />
```