# Sharing Google maps or taking screen shot of android phone

Tags: android, facebook, google-maps

I'm developing android app using android google map api v2. **I have achieved following so far**

-opens google map showing user's location

-as he walks he can add  markers to the map (marking the places he pass by)

-he can remove markers or drag them

**What I want to do now is**

when the user finishes the walk he/she can share their map (with their marker on it!)on social networks>>mainly Facebook.

Is that possible? and how do people share maps?

If not, is there a way I can at east take a screen shot of the map,save it locally on SD as an img and share it of facebook?

Would appreciate your suggestions!
**Update**
Tried to use this method onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) but my app crashes when I click the imge button3 that is supposed to call button_listener().help please!

```
private void button_listener() {
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                        Bitmap bitmap;

                        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            bitmap = snapshot;
                            try {
                                   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Download/TeleSensors.png");
                                   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    mMap.snapshot(callback);}
```

Comment: Hi the Google maps api v2 for android have a method for take a snapshot please check this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback

Answer (score 0):

Hi the Google maps api v2 for android have a method for take a snapshot please check this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback

Comment: thax @ingyesid Im trying with this method now.my app crashes and i dont know why? my code above