# Android-> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

i've tried all the solutions given in similar question, but still could not eliminate the error in inflating class fragment while using maps. Infact, my code is exactly the same as given in one of the solution of similar question but still the code dosen't run.

----------------------AndroidManifest.xml-------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lavisor.mapsdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<permission 
 android:name="com.lavisor.mapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
 android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWoRK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.lavisor.mapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                 android:value="AIzaSyB-c6JFjix-A5D8dMkTyHkmsmrElEhL7Bc"/>

    <meta-data   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

-----------------------activity_main.xml-----------------------------

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.lavisor.mapsdemo.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

--------------------------activity_map.xml----------------------------------

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <fragment 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 />
```

-------------------MainActivity.xml--------------------------

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private static final int GPS_ERRORCODE_CONST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(servicesOK())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Preparing Map... " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


    }

    else{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

 }



 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

//to check if google play services are available on device

 public boolean servicesOK()
 {
    int isAvailable;

    isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        return true;

    }
    else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable))
    {

        Dialog diag = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,this, GPS_ERRORCODE_CONST);
        diag.show();
    }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot Connect to Google Play Services " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;

   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps V2 - Error inflating class Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740048/google-maps-v2-error-inflating-class-fragment)

Comment: It's a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740048/google-maps-v2-error-inflating-class-fragment - it also contains the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Still dosen't work... i tried all the possible solutions, but same error only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent my time reading the logcat error log fully and found that it told me to add this in my manifest file -->>

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And it worked like a charm... I was searching for a solution for a day .. . but all I had to do was to read the error log fully...

Answer (score 0):

you should try using `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

Also, make sure your build.gradle has
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0`

---

Edit
try use

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

instead of a

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Comment: Actually i'm using eclipse, not android studios..and i changed MapFragment to SupportMapFragment.. still not working..

Comment: Oh ok on Eclipse. Have you imported Google Play Services as Lib Project ? (not only a jar) This point is important.

Comment: I tried to run other  Google mapV2 example and same error occurs.. please someone help me get through. I downloaded  The example map project from  --> http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/