# Error inflating class fragment Why do i get this error when i resume an Activity with Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing an Android application which uses Google maps.
I have been facing this error

> Error inflating class fragment

whenever i Resume an Activity with Google maps fragment and my app crashes.
Below is my Logcat

```js
03-08 15:50:43.930 6316-6316/com.extrainch.sendas E/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.extrainch.sendas, PID: 6316
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.extrainch.sendas/com.extrainch.sendas.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4210)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:178)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at com.extrainch.sendas.fragments.PickupFragment$override.onCreateView(PickupFragment.java:98)
at com.extrainch.sendas.fragments.PickupFragment$override.access$dispatch(PickupFragment.java)
at com.extrainch.sendas.fragments.PickupFragment.onCreateView(PickupFragment.java:0)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1523)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1585)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2832)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:603)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:181)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1244)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2478)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4210) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:178) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07000e type #0x3 is not valid
at android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:786)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fq.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:2099)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fq.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:64)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:367)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:320)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cp.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:139)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.w.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:385)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
at
```

My fragment in the xml looks like this

```js
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My question is why do i keep on getting this error when the Activity is resumed and What am i doing wrong?
Please help.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740048/google-maps-v2-error-inflating-class-fragment) if it can help you.

Comment: @KENdi this didn't work for me