# Using MapFragment with min sdk-8

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-api-2

I wish to use google maps in my app. For that, I am using MapFragment. MapFragment requires minimum sdk version 11. But I wish to have minimum sdk version as 8 so that my app works for Android 2.2 and above. When I use MapView I do not get the map. I just get the grids in the map. How do I resolve this?
Need Help.

Comment: MapView is deprecated, and I wouldn't count on it being available forever. Do you absolutely need to have Android 2.2 support?

Comment: Yes!! I need the app to support Android 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of Map Fragment use `SupportMapFragment`

Read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment)

and Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083334/792232) SO answer . As Jeo Malin said dont use `MapView` It is deprecated. Use MapV2

Study [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) .