# Unable to instantiate android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I have a view with a facebook style side bar navigation. On the main view I want to display my map. I have followed Google's tutorial exactly! But I keep running into the error Unable to instantiate android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.

I did manage to run this on a plain project but when I merge it with my main project this error pops up:

```
07-25 13:27:53.778: E/AndroidRuntime(24841): 
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment:
make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

I tried the answers posted below but the problem persists.

["Error inflating class fragment" with google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082851/error-inflating-class-fragment-with-google-map)

and also this one:

[Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in Google Map V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572020/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment)

The reference to the google sdk in project properties is also set. 
Here is the class:

```
    public class SlideAnimationThenCallLayout extends FragmentActivity implements AnimationListener {

View menu;
View app;

boolean menuOut = false;
AnimParams animParams = new AnimParams();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_animation_then_call_layout);


    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(){

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            swipeAnimation();

        }

    });
    RelativeLayout listview3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    listview3.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(){

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            swipeAnimation();

        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            swipeAnimation();

        }
    });
    menu = findViewById(R.id.menu);
    app = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

}
```

The xml file is:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/action_eating">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/android_homescreen">

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know what is wrong here now. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by you error:

> Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment:
>   make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

and the fact the `SupportManFragment` class is part of the `google-play-services` library, you problem is surtenly in the way you reference this library or the library it self.

I would suggest you to re-download it using the SDK-Manager and move it to a location where it path would be shorter and then try to reference it again using the answer you have in this question:

[Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in Google Map V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572020/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment)

Comment: It worked! Just deleted the old google play project and imported it again! Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project ---> Android Tools ---> Add Support Library.
Download it and clear the project and build again. Hope it will work

Comment: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public