# Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I followed all the steps from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_app_settings_in_the_application_manifest
 But I am still getting a crash when executing this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
```

The code is being invoked by a button click listener, located in my onCreate method.

Before pressing the button, everything works as expected, but as soon as i press the button to display the google map, i get a crash.

Here's my logcat (edited after trying suggestions).

```
05-25 18:41:03.357 : W/dalvikvm(21600): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41655438)
05-25 18:41:03.383 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 18:41:03.399 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-25 18:41:03.418 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-25 18:41:03.436 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-25 18:41:03.454 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-25 18:41:03.477 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-25 18:41:03.496 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-25 18:41:03.519 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
05-25 18:41:03.538 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
05-25 18:41:03.561 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at com.Actividad.Brian.actividad$12.run(actividad.java:2389)
05-25 18:41:03.590 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at com.Actividad.Brian.actividad.Google_Maps(actividad.java:2393)
05-25 18:41:03.619 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at com.Actividad.Brian.actividad$4.run(actividad.java:1066)
05-25 18:41:03.639 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-25 18:41:03.664 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 18:41:03.693 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 18:41:03.723 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
05-25 18:41:03.754 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 18:41:03.779 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 18:41:03.800 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-25 18:41:03.824 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-25 18:41:03.858 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 18:41:03.898 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-25 18:41:03.924 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
05-25 18:41:03.962 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
05-25 18:41:04.002 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4696)
05-25 18:41:04.028 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
05-25 18:41:04.062 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     ... 18 more
05-25 18:41:04.106 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
05-25 18:41:04.133 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-25 18:41:04.164 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-25 18:41:04.198 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-25 18:41:04.227 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
05-25 18:41:04.269 : E/AndroidRuntime(21600):     ... 21 more
```

Here is map_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

My activity is rather big but this reproduces the behaviour without having to push anything:

```
public class actividad extends Activity
{
    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
    }
}
```

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.Actividad.Brian"
   android:versionName="1.01" android:installLocation="internalOnly"
   android:versionCode="1">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<permission android:name="com.Actividad.Brian.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.Actividad.Brian.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_SERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Actividad" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAYJTp4zzcPD8K_**INTENTIONAL**2R7Y" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
    <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name=".actividad" android:label="Actividad" android:screenOrientation="portrait"  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Do you see any errors that i may be overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **android-support-v4.jar** form your project and move **google-play-services.jar** to the top of the list of References list. You should be reado to roll with that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up a root layout for your activity, which is holding the fragment in your xml code. Here is an example with a LinearLayout as a root layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent" 
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the instructions found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map it states: "Replace the entire contents of that file with the following code.". However, i will try.

Comment: If thats not helping, you can try to leave your xml code (only the fragment) and extending from FragmentActivity. That should work, too. But you're right, the documentation says something else.

Comment: I already tried that, but then my app crashes even before. Upon trying your suggestion the logcat showed two new hints, one of them is:

Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Comment: You can try the first post of that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853027/unable-to-instantiate-android-gms-maps-supportmapfragment
That seems to help.

Comment: Still no go. I might need to hire someone to do it for me. :(