# Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a little issue with my android app.
So i have a maps fragment, and i'm trying to put a listview under it.
The error occurs when i Try to populate the listview, it does show empty before, but once i bind it to the adapter it gives me this error :

> 01-21 20:43:17.635 19597-19597/boxcom.secondattempt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-21 20:43:17.635 19597-19597/boxcom.secondattempt E/AndroidRuntime: Process: boxcom.secondattempt, PID: 19597
>   01-21 20:43:17.635 19597-19597/boxcom.secondattempt E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment

Here is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main_menu" tools:context="boxcom.secondattempt.MainMenu">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:layout_gravity="top|bottom"></fragment>

        <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listv"
                    android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue"
                    android:layout_width="354dp"
                    android:layout_height="187dp"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and where I populate :

```
public void init_endroits()
{
    Place A = new Place();
    Place B = new Place();
    Place C = new Place();

    A.setName("Café A");
    B.setName("Restaurant B");
    C.setName("Musée C");
    A.setDescription("C'est un café");
    B.setDescription("C'est un restaurant");
    C.setDescription("C'est un Musée");

    ListView LV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);
    Endroits.add(A);
    Endroits.add(B);
    Endroits.add(C);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Place>(this,R.layout.activity_main_menu,Endroits);
    LV.setAdapter(adapter);
    LV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {
            Place X = Endroits.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, X.getDescription().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
```

I call this method after everything is loaded, when I press a button in the navbar.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Which line is line 22?

Comment: Are you using FragmentActivity?

Comment: No I am not using fragment activity

Comment: public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, android.location.LocationListener {

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing this is a duplicate of [“Error inflating class fragment” with google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082851/error-inflating-class-fragment-with-google-map) stackoverflow question, as you are using support AppCompatActivity with MapFragment.

Replace MapFragment with SupportMapFragment, and that should clear up this specific crash.

Comment: I've just changed every MapFragment to SupportMapFragment, changed it in the xml too by using com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment instead, same error :(

Comment: Did you try using FragmentActivity instead?

Comment: I'm using a navbar + sidebar layout, if i make it extend FragmentActivity instead i think it might break it, no?

Comment: I just changed it, and commented out the navbar part, it still gives me the same goddamn error >:(
ty tho

Comment: I removed the fragment and left only the list view, gave me this error : ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: It's fixed ! I fixed the text view issue, then put back the fragment and i don't have the error anymore, thanks for the help guys

Comment: What was the issue exactly? Please share it so that it will help others.